# C# Entity Framework Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to the Entity Framework, so I created a little test-project.
I have the following Models in my Project:

```
class Books
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}

class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to receive all Books with a related author, but it fails...

```
using (WFCDbContext db = new WFCDbContext())
{
    List<Books> = db.Books.Where(x => x.Author == myAuthorVariable).toList()
}
```

ErrorMessage:

> Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this
>   context.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] including the declaration and population of `myAuthorVariable`.

Comment: Note that this wouldn't work in LINQ-to-objects either because two Author instances having the same property values are not "equal".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity framework has no idea what to do with your `myAuthorVariable` reference, i.e. how would it translate that to *SQL*? *SQL* has no concept of references.

Basically, what you would want to do in this situation is give it a primitive type it can translate into *SQL* Like an `Id`

```
using (WFCDbContext db = new WFCDbContext())
{
    List<Books> = db.Books.Where(x => x.Author.Id == myAuthorVariable.Id).toList()
}
```

Comment: oh god so damn simple.. thanks!

Comment: @MathisHüttl no problems, good luck